# Windows 2003 R2 Missing mapped drives under ODBC Administrator

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003-r2, odbc

When I try to set up an ODBC datasource (MS Access) I can't select the network drive where the mdb file is.

The network drive is accesible from My Computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapped drives are usually not available to system processes since the mapping is tied to an interactive user session. Try using a UNC path to the file instead.